# Pinescript version 4 Month Open

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I am trying to plot monthly open in version 4.

However the levels are shifted forward (to right) by a month i.e. September open is marked at 1st Oct, October open is marked at 1st Nov., and so on.

The code is pretty simple and it works fine in older versions.

```
//@version=4
m_open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", open)
plot(m_open, title="Month Open", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.black)
```

For **older** versions, where instead of *syminfo.tickerid* only *tickerid* is written.

**Result**

[image]

I have checked few other question about v1 to v4, however, they do not address changes related to syminfo.

Answer (score -1):

```
//@version=4
study(title="TEST", overlay=true)

var float m_open = na

new_month = change(month)

if new_month
    m_open := open
    
plot(m_open, title="Month Open", style=plot.style_linebr, color=new_month?na:color.blue)
```